# Usefulness of [gtpay] tag?

Tags: discussion

I've never heard of [gtpay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtpay) (that could be my own ignorance). It appears there's only one question with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtpay.

Is there a need for it? If not, would it be possible to get rid of the tag?

Answer (score 1):

Of course the tag is useful. It's about a certain API, we have hundreds if not thousands of similar tags.

For reference, this is what [the one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256519/gtpay-nigeria-payment-api-documentation-needed) with that tag said (it was posted some 20 minutes before this Meta question):

> I am trying to integrate GTPAY Payment API. I got this link from my client but there is no proper examples
>
> ```
> https://ibank.gtbank.com/GTPay/Test/mman-tech.html
> ```
>
> Any one have idea or any integrated using REST APIs ?

That you have never heard of it before may have something to do with the API being for a Nigerian bank and you living in the US.

To be frank, if you had taken one minute to look up what *gtpay* is, you wouldn't have needed to post this Meta discussion.

Comment: @Stijn- Forgive my ignorance, but what does me looking up a technology have to do with the usefulness of the tag?

Comment: @jww I was under the impression that you argued the tag is not useful because it's about an obscure technology. Are you instead arguing that it's not useful because it only had one question?